# While using read()/readline() in python, continuously with the same fileobject instance, some of the data that i am reading is ignored

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

Textfile.txt:
Hello World
Hello World

Script:

```
def read(bytes):
    with open("Textfile.txt", "r") as File1:
        print(File1.read(bytes))
        print(File1.read(bytes))

read(5)
```

Output:

Hello

Worl

For the first read(bytes) statement, the first 5 elements are read and i am not sure why the first 5 contents of the file is ignored during the second read(bytes) statement.

Any reason why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The space between the hello and world is a charater as well, so "hello" and " Worl" are both 5 characters each, as expected